# Como exibir variavel char no LCD do Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Eu estava tentando imprimir uma variavel char no LCD do arduino mas nao consigo, sempre da erro quando tento compilar o codigo.
Ja puxei a biblioteca do LCD e a linha que tento imprimir eh a seguinte:

```
lcd.print("%c",letra);
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Agradeco desde ja!

Comment: É interessante também informar qual o erro que ocorre!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma coisa que é importante saber a respeito de displays LCDs é que eles possuem uma memória interna. O Arduino simplesmente ativa o modo de leitura ou escrita e envia um endereço de memória com o caractere que você quer imprimir através do barramento. A figura a seguir mostra os caracteres disponíveis:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Se você quiser imprimir um caractere diferente](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalCreateChar), existe uma outra memória onde você envia um array de bytes contendo os pixels ativos e inativos que formarão seu novo caractere. Como na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto ao seu problema, acho que as seguintes linhas de código podem resolver:

```
//char variavel = 'a';
//lcd.print(char(variavel);     //Isto deveria funcionar
//lcd.print((char)223);         //Isto também

char caractere = 'b';
lcd.print(caractere, BIN);
//ou...
int charcode = 65;
lcd.print(charcode);
```

Como o LCD recebe um dado em binário, você deve informar isto através do "BIN". Assim o Arduino vai enviar o valor em binário correspondente ao caractere através do barramento.

Comment: Obrigado! Ainda nao testei no arduino em si mas ja vi que deu pra compilar, provavelmente resolveu meu problema!!

Comment: Obrigado. Se não der certo me avisa. :)